# defining row grids within a column grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid with 3 defined columns. Is there a way to divide column 1 into 3 grid rows without affecting the other 2 columns? I've tried defining RowDefinitions, but it spans all 3 columns. I don't want that. I only want it to affect the 1 column.

Comment: Is it a GridView control? or a regular table?

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/window/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowspan.aspx?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. If you declare a `Row` inside `Grid` it will be for all the `Columns`.

One thing you can do is declare a `Grid` inside the first `Column` and define three rows in that `Grid`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition/>
             <RowDefinition/>
             <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested Grids. Put an inner Grid into column 1 and define some rows:

```
<Grid Name="outerGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="innerGrid" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this layout:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>                
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```